# office javascript add-in ribbon standard commands like copy or cut

Tags: office-js, office-js-helpers

We have add-in where we create ribbon with standard buttons like copy,paste etc and then add our own buttons for managing the format of document. We are developing it in office-js add-in. Can the same functionality achieve AFAIK I cannot but would like you all to comment considering you are pro in this field.

Thanks in advance
Manoj

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call existing commands in an Office Add-in Command. But, depending on what you want to do you might be able to implement the existing command using Office.js.

Comment: Thanks for info here are some stuff we do.


Cut 
Copy
Bold
Italic
Underline
Subscript
Superscript
AlignLeft
AlignCenter
AlignRight
NavigationPaneFind
ReplaceDialog
PageBreakInsertWord
PictureInsertFromFile
Other Cross-Reference
InsertBuildingBlocksEquationsGallery
TableInsertDialogWord
TableRepeatHeaderRows
WebGoBack
WebGoForward